# Access violation writing location?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function to reverse a string, but I got such exception when I am doing:  *str++ = *end;   anyone who knows what's the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
void reverse(char* str)
 {
    char *end = str;
    char temp;
    if(str)
    {
      while(*end)
       {
     end++;
       }
    end--;

    while(str<end)
    {
       temp = *str;
       *str++ = *end;
       *end--=temp;
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How do you call this method? Because a conversion from a string literal to a `char*` is deprecated and in this case it brings errors.

Answer (score 5):

Chances are, you called the function with a string literal:

```
 reverse("ablewasiereisawelba");
```

You can't modify string literals without invoking undefined behaviour, and crash is a valid response to an attempt to modify a string literal.  Make sure you pass a non-constant array instead:

```
 char palindrome[] = "ablewasiereisawelba";
 reverse(palindrome);
```

The C++ 2011 standard, ISO/IEC 14882:2011 says:

> #### 2.14.5 String literal [lex.string]
>
> ¶12 The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.

Commonly, string literals are placed in readonly memory, and an attempt to modify one leads to a 'crash'.  That is certainly a perfectly legitimate response to invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: `You can't modify string literals.` Isn't it actually UB? (asking because not sure, not criticising)

Comment: Yes, it is undefined behavior IIRC.

Comment: C++ standard ISO/IEC 14882:2011 §2.14.5 _String literals_ says: "The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined." so it is undefined behaviour.  Commonly, string literals are placed in readonly memory, and an attempt to modify one leads to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do this:

```
 char str[] = "My string to reverse!";

 reverse(str);
```

This means that `str` is stored in modifiable memory. Most modern compilers store literal strings (that is 'anything within quotes' in read-only memory, because you are not meant to modify the original string).